# How can BeautifulSoup access elements that exclusively contain certain classes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

It is my understanding that if each class is contained in a list (e.g. `e.find('div', {'class':['class1', 'class2']})`), elements with *any* of those classes would be returned.

Does BeautifulSoup have a filter that would find elements that only contain all listed classes?

Comment: Do you know if it would be better to delete or vote to close as a duplicate?

Comment: vote to close as duplicate, this way if someone search and find this question (and not the other one) he will get the link to the other.